# Minimum of function of x and y

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

any ideas how to find minimum of the following function:
$f(x,y)=a-b\frac{x}{y}-c\frac{y}{x}+\frac{d}{x}+\frac{e}{y}-\frac{g}{xy}$.
Assume that $a,b,c,d,e,g>0$. We can also assume that $x,y \ge 1$.
Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the maximum or the minimum?

Comment: Maybe you should try to find where the gradient vanishes in order to know where are the critical points of $f$.

Comment: @user84413  minimum. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @Surb. How would I do that? just take partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes, you could solve $$\left\{\begin{array}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) = 0 \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y) = 0 \end{array} \right.$$
which is equivalent as solving a system of two equations of degree $2$ with two unknowns (should be faisable). Then you know all the critical points of your function and you can find the optimal one you want.

Answer (score 1):

In the region $x,y \ge 1$ we have them each nonzero, so that the partials $f_x,f_y$ may be multiplied by products using $x,y.$ We have
$$x^2yf_x=-bx^2+cy^2-dy+g,\\ xy^2f_y=bx^2-cy^2-ex+g.$$
Both of these must be zero at any critical point, so that on adding them we see any critical point lies on the line $L:ex+dy=2g.$ Trying to solve this for say $y$ and put it back into either one of the partials and get the possible $x$ values is an awful mess.

However since in your problem we have the boundaries $y=1,x \ge 1$ and $x=1,y\ge 1$ there is hope of solving the minimum, at least in a specific case. See if the line $L$ contains any points in the interior. If it does, parametrize $L$ there and get a one variable function after plugging into $f(x,y)$ and find the min on that part (one variable calc). In any case one must also parametrize the two horizontal and vertical parts of the boundary, and again by one variable calculus find the minimums of those. Of course the overall minimum is the smallest of these three (or two) subresults.

**Important Edit:** I went too quickly and tried to apply the usual critical point and check the boundary method to this problem. The issue is that it doesn't apply here, since the domain in question is not a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2.$ That is, one has to check what happens as $x,y \to \infty$ in this example, if looking for min (or max).

In this example one can see there is actually no minimum by defining $t=x/y$ so that $x=ty$ and the objective function becomes
$$a-bt-\frac{c}{t}+\frac{d}{ty}+\frac{e}{y}-\frac{g}{ty^2}. \tag{*}$$
Now one can certainly in the region $x,y\ge 1$ make both $t,y$ approach $+\infty$ since all that implies is that $x=ty \to \infty$ also. But then all terms of $(*)$ other than the first two approach zero, while $a-bt \to -\infty.$ Thus in fact the function $f(x,y)$ has no minimum in the given region $x,y \ge 1.$ There may well be a maximum, I didn't check that since not asked in the question. Actually $f(x,y)$ is bounded above by $a+d+e$ given positivity of the coefficients and $x,y\ge 1.$ Then the max or sup must exist.